# How to call backend methods from JS independent from Vaadin View?

Tags: javascript, java, vaadin, vaadin14

I have the following scenario. Javascript is executed in the frontend and reacts on events. If an event is catched a specific backend method is called.

I initialize the backend like the following. The method is called during the initialization of one of my **Vaadin 14** views.

```
window.init = function(element) {
    window.element = element;
    ...
}
```

View:

```
public class TestView extends Div {
   public TestView() {
      ...
      UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("init($0)", this);
   }
}
```

later on the methods are called with `window.element.$server.onTestEvent();` on the frontend.

The called backend method:

```
@ClientCallable
private void onTestEvent() {
    System.out.println("Test");
}
```

Now the issue:

I pass the view as `element`.

If I change the view the `element` I passed is destroyed so the event (on the backend side) can't be executed even if it is catched on the frontend.

Does **Vaadin 14** provide a way to store objects "globally" over all views? I want the application to react on the events independent on which view I currently visit.

Comment: FYI: [*An introduction to client-side TypeScript views in Vaadin 15*](https://vaadin.com/blog/an-introduction-to-client-side-typescript-views-in-vaadin-15)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use the element of a top-level main layout (view container / MainView) instead of individual views' elements.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am using the element of my MainView and it works.